# Meaning of "would have had"?

Tags: present-perfect, ambiguity

I saw an ad regarding a job opportunity, where the following line was written:

> Typically, you would have had 3+years of experience building software
>   products.

Does it mean that the candidate must mandatorily have 3+ years of experience?

And even if it does, some lines down, it's stated so:

> Education and Experience: Bachelor’s Degree in Computer
>   Science/Engineering. Masters preferred.

Now I am confused whether this is for a fresher or an experienced candidate.

This is the page :
[Job Opportunity Ad](https://opentextats.avature.net/careers/JobDetail/Bangalore-India-Software-Engineer/14584)

Comment: No fresh candidates need apply. They require that the candidate have at least 3+ years of experience. The requirement below doesn't mention experience after the colon! They require a BS in Comp Sci or Eng, and candidates with an MS go to the head of the line. (This is a misuse of the preterit of the verb _will_. The sentence is properly _"Typically, you **will** have had 3+years of experience building software products."_ Even that is unnecessary. There is no reason to use any but the simple present of _have_ here: _"Typically, you have 3+years of experience building software products."_)

Comment: wow I didn't notice that : "The requirement below doesn't mention experience after the colon" thanks dude :)

Comment: Please move your comment to answers @P.E.Dant

Answer (score 1):

That link no longer works, but what you've quoted is a very awkward posting. While using the word typically would not generally imply required, I suspect that the author was intending to convey that 3 or more years were indeed required for the position. I have not ever heard the term "fresher" but in general, when a posting requires a particular level of education plus experience, they are not looking for "new college hires" or someone who has only just graduated. They are looking for both; a particular education requirement plus a particular experience requirement. Some recent graduates may fulfill these requirements if they have been working in an internship or other pre-graduate, software-development position.

In this particular case, it is likely they are intending to require a bachelor's degree, while a master's degree is preferred and requiring three or more years of software development experience. However, the posting is unclear, so it would not hurt to ask HR for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a requirement to have "3+ years" of experience.  The word "typically" means that the employer expects that most successful candidates "will have had 3+ years of experience", but it is possible for a successful candidate to have less experience.

The job description implies that the employer wants a candidate who has more experience than someone who is "fresh out of college", but does not need a candidate who has many years of experience.  There are many things that an employee learns in their first "real-world job".  If you cannot make a list of things you learned in your first computer programming job, you probably do not have enough experience for this position.